# How to use AutoIt to set Internet Explorer options?

Tags: java, eclipse, internet-explorer, automation, autoit

I need to use AutoIt to change the emulation mode in Internet Explorer.

Basically I need to open the "developer tools" (F12), change the document mode to emulate IE 10.

AutoIt is up and running in my IDE (Eclipse). I already can open IE, what are my doubts:

1. How can I simulate opening the debug options?

[image]

2. How can I change the emulation version?

[image]

I just created a new instance of AutoIt and know how to open IE:

```
package autotioficial;

import java.io.File;

import com.jacob.com.LibraryLoader;

import autoitx4java.AutoItX;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("lib", "jacob-1.18-x86.dll"); //path to the jacob dll
    System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());

    AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
    x.run("C:/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe");

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use keystrokes to do this:

```
x.send("{F12}") //go to developer mode
x.send("^8") //control-8 to go to Emulation tab
x.send("{TAB}") //select the first field (Document mode)
x.send("10") //set emulated version to E10
```

I checked manually, this works on Explorer 11. The change is not very persistent though, watch for browser history resets etc (http://appliedusers.ca/forums/index.php?topic=5330.0).

References:
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Send.htm
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/appendix/SendKeys.htm

Comment: Bookeater, thanks for answering, the problem is, how to click on that option, in the printscreen I clicked with the mouse...

Comment: @Leonardo Leonardo, so the option is not selected after pressing F12? (x.send("{F12}"))

Comment: I added ^8 that selects the emulation tab. Now it just needs to activate the list you are after, then send("10") will work.

Comment: @Leonardo Leonardo, Did another edit, checked manually against E11.